# Question about partitions and primes.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n = P$ , where $P$ stands for the set of odd primes $<\sqrt{x}$ and $A_i$ is nonempty. Also $\#A_k\gg \# A_l$ iff $k>l$ ($\#$ is cardinality ).

In fact we consider the partition of $P$ into $A_n$.

Also every prime in $A_a$ is smaller than any prime in $A_b$ iff $a<b$.

Let $a_r$ be some element of $A_r$ or $a_r=1$.

How many numbers are there of the form $\prod_{r=1}^n a_r$ between $3$ and $x$ ?

In particular I wondered about the case where $\# A_m= 2^{2^m} + 1$ for almost all $m$.

Comment: tnx for edit. unbelievable I missed that.

Comment: I changed $>>$ to $\gg$.

Comment: Mertens theorems are usefull here.